# How to change opacity rule of child on hover using only CSS?

Tags: css

How can I change opacity of child `li`s on hovering on parent only using core CSS?

The following code is changing the opacity whilw hovering over the child lis but I need to do this on hovering over the parent li

```css
ul li> ul li{
  background:khaki;
  opacity:0;
}

ul li> ul li:hover{
  opacity:1;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>App 1</li>
  <li>App
    <ul>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>App 1</li>
  <li>App 1   </li>
      <li> App
    <ul>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `:hover` to the parent of the sub menus (`li:hover > ul`):

```css
ul li > ul li {
  background: khaki;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:hover > ul li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>App 1</li>
  <li>App
    <ul>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>App 1</li>
  <li>App 1 </li>
  <li> App
    <ul>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
      <li>App 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```